# EF Insert new enity with Many-to-Many relationship creates duplicate records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two classes..

```
class Assembly
{
    public Assembly()
    {
        this.Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }

    public int AssemblyId { get; set; }
    public string PartNum { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int workMins { get; set; }
    public List<Assembly> Assemblies { get; set; }
}
```

These classes are set up with a many-to-many relationship.

I have a list of tasks that have already been saved to the database and I am trying to add one of these tasks to a new assembly.

The issue I am haing is when I try to create the new assembly with tasks and save it to the database.

```
            using (CapacityContext ctx = new CapacityContext())
            {
                Assembly a = new Assembly();
                a.PartNum = cmbPartNum.Text;
                a.Desc = txtDesc.Text;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in gridTasks.Rows)
                {
                    int taskId = Convert.ToInt16(dr.Cells[colTaskId.Name].Value);
                    Task at = Task.GetTaskById(taskId);
                    a.Tasks.Add(at);
                }

                ctx.Assemblies.Add(a);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Once the changes are sent to the database, a new Task is inserted to the Tasks table that is identical except that it has a new TaskId. I checked the entitiy before it is saved and the correct task with the correct taskId is added, so I'm at a loss about what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit:**
For anyone else who runs into this, I found the problem. I had created this method

```
    public static Task GetTaskById(int id)
    {
        using (CapacityContext ctx = new CapacityContext())
        {
            try
            {
                return ctx.Tasks.Find(id);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

which retrieves a taks by its id. This was the cause of the problem as it's a no-no to insert an entitiy using a Find() from a different context. Once I moved `ctx.Tasks.Find(id);` inside the same method that creates the assembly, it worked fine!

Comment: What does this do? `Task at = Task.GetTaskById(taskId);` Could you try `Task at = new Task{Name = "testing new value"};` this instead to see if it is saved correctly.

Comment: You should place your Edit as an answer below and then accept your own answer so that other users can easily recognize that the problem is solved.